# What's the word for "preferring this option/choice"

Tags: single-word-requests

Context:

I have two options to spend the coming summer, one would be to find a internship job and the other one would be to just relax and maybe try to do one of my projects that I have been telling you about lately. Honestly, I am ***_*__** to/for taking a break and start a project or two - I feel that I need it.

The word I'm looking for is similar in the sense to "leaning" or "biased", but both of these words can't be used here.

Comment: What do you mean, they can't be used here?

Comment: @user545424: I mean I think that they wouldn't be the best words to use in this context

Comment: @RoronoaZoro, do you mean it's not formal enough?

Comment: @Bidella, not really. I meant that a typical English speaker wouldn't use either of them.

Comment: @RoronoaZoro, actually, they would. It's something pretty common to say.

Comment: WRT the sentence "I am ___ to/for taking a break and start a project or two." You should not say, "taking a break and start a project." because it is not balanced. You have to say, "taking a break and **starting** a project." And you have to use "toward" for leaning/biased (rather than "to"). "Honestly, I am biased/leaning towards taking a break and starting a project or two."

Comment: btw, *an* internship. And the word 'job' is not needed, 'internship' is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the others, there's nothing wrong with *leaning*.

If you wanted a stronger word, you might consider one of these:

> I am *yearning* for a break.
>   I am *desperate* for a break.

You could also say:

> I am *ready* for a break.
>   I'd *prefer* to take a break.

Or even (more informally):

> I am *more than ready* for a break.

Answer (score 5):

"Honestly, I am leaning towards taking a break." is what I would say.

Answer (score 2):

@user545424 is absolutely right. That's an option which is quite common among English speakers.

If you're not satisfied, you could try:

> I am favouring taking a break.
>   I am inclined towards taking a break.

Comment: I would change your second to, "I am inclined to take a break," in my own usage.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you need to say something like this:

***Honestly, I intend to take a break this summer, and work on a few projects that need my time.***

Comment: That's not imperative.

Comment: oops... ammended.

Answer (score 1):

I am `predisposed` to option-a.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit elitist but you could use

Honestly, I am **minded** to take a break and start a project or two

Answer (score 0):

Following the same semi/ non-formal style and in the given context, ***like*** should be a nice option:

> I am more like taking a break ...

or,

> I would really like to take a break ...